# How to check if a number in my contacts is registered to Whatsapp?

Tags: android, class, apk, whatsapp

But I need this with numbers with country codes (like starting with +123 456 78 90 -that's the way I add the number as a contact)
I need a function/class to check if this number has Whatsapp.
I need this for an .apk I made in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void getAllWhatsappNumbers()
{
    //This class provides applications access to the content model.
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

//RowContacts for filter Account Types
    Cursor contactCursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID},
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
            new String[]{"com.whatsapp"},
            null);



    if (contactCursor != null) {
        if (contactCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //whatsappContactId for get Number,Name,Id ect... from  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                    String whatsappContactId = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));

                    if (whatsappContactId != null) {
                        //Get Data from ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone of Specific CONTACT_ID
                        Cursor whatsAppContactCursor = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME},
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{whatsappContactId}, null);

                        if (whatsAppContactCursor != null) {
                            whatsAppContactCursor.moveToFirst();
                            String id = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                            String name = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            String number = whatsAppContactCursor.getString(whatsAppContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            Log.d("log1","no:"+number+"name:"+name);
                            whatsAppContactCursor.close();

                            //Add Number to ArrayList
                            myWhatsappContactsNumbers.add(number);
                        }
                    }
                } while (contactCursor.moveToNext());
                contactCursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this function provided, we can get contact list on "com.whatsapp"
We put this contact list in to the array list so we need a function to show us we the number we sent is in the list (true) or not (false). How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

for first thing you need to have contact name and also social media package name and package name mimetype (like whatsapp >> packagename: com.whatsapp, packageMimetype: com.whatsapp)

after that this code return you that this number have selected social media or not with a boolean. :)

```
    fun hasSocialMedia(contactName: String, socialMediaPackage: String, socialMediaMimeType: String, normilizeNumber: String?) : Boolean {
    var hasSelectedSocialMedia = false

    val cursor1: Cursor = _context.contentResolver.query(
        RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
        arrayOf(RawContacts._ID),
        RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " = ?",
        arrayOf(socialMediaPackage, contactName),
        null
    )!!
    while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
        val rawContactId = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID))
        val cursor2: Cursor = _context.contentResolver.query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            arrayOf(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3),
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? ",
            arrayOf("vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.$socialMediaMimeType.profile", rawContactId),
            null
        )!!

        while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
            var phoneNumber = cursor2.getString(0)
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) continue
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "")

            if (phoneNumber.contains(normilizeNumber.toString(), true)) hasSelectedSocialMedia = true
            else continue
        }
        cursor2.close()
    }

    cursor1.close()

    return hasSelectedSocialMedia;
}
```

Comment: @Elikill58 I improved my code, sorry for late :)

Comment: No problem, take your time :) And that's better now !

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to check whether the contact no is registered on WhatsApp or not. But you can do one thing to check whether no is registered on WhatsApp or not.

Just pass that number to WhatsApp application using explicit intent and after passing to WhatsApp, WhatsApp open one popup which says "**The given no is registered on WhatsApp**" by this you can get to know whether no is registered or not.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
     sendIntent.putExtra("jid", whatsAppNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");
     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "whatsAppMessage");
     sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
     sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b");
     sendIntent.setType("text/*");
     startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Here "com.whatsapp.w4b" is used for the Business WhatsApp application if you want to use normal WhatsApp then you just need to change com.whatsapp.w4b to com.whatsapp

whatsAppNumber is a number to which you want to send the WhatsApp a message

Or Second way is to find a contact from internal contact data

```
ArrayList<String> whatsAppContact = new ArrayList();
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
    RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
    RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
    new String[] { "com.whatsapp" },
    null);
ArrayList<String> myWhatsappContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
int name = 
c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
while (c.moveToNext())
{
whatsAppContact.add(c.getString(name));
 }
```